# C++ C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'Node<T> *const ' to 'Iterator<const T>'

Tags: c++, templates

I have been trying to create iterator for my Linked List implementations. But i am getting an error. My implementation is below:

```
#ifndef LinkedListIterative_h
#define LinkedListIterative_h

#include <cstdio>

using std::swap;

template <typename T>
class LinkedList;

template <typename T>
class Iterator;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
    private:
        friend class Iterator<T>;
        friend class LinkedList<T>;        

        T data;
        Node *next;

        Node() : next(nullptr) {}
        Node(const T& data) : data(data) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Iterator
{
    private:
        Node<T> *node;

    public:
        Iterator() : node(nullptr) {}

        Iterator(Node<T> *node) : node(node)  {}

        Iterator(const Node<T> *node) : node(node)  {}

        Iterator(const Iterator& iterator) : node(iterator.node)
        {

        }

        Iterator& operator= (const Iterator& rhs)
        {
            if( this != &rhs )
            {
                node = rhs.node;
            }
        }

        Iterator& operator++()
        {
            node = node->next;

            return *this;
        }

        Iterator& operator+(size_t index)
        {
            while( index-- > 0 && (node != nullptr) )
            {
                ++this;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        Iterator& operator[](size_t index)
        {
            while( index-- > 0 && (node != nullptr) )
            {
                ++this;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const Iterator &iter)
        {
            return node == iter.node;
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator &iter)
        {
            return node != iter.node;
        }

        T& operator*() { return node->data; }

};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    private:
        size_t size;
        Node<T> *first;
        Node<T> *last;

        Node<T>* createNode(const T &item)
        {
            Node<T> *node = new Node<T>;

            node->data = item;
            node->next = nullptr;

            return node;
        }

        LinkedList(const LinkedList& list){}

        LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList& list){}

    public:
        typedef Iterator<T> iterator;
        typedef Iterator<const T> const_iterator;

        LinkedList() : size(0), first(nullptr), last(nullptr)
        {

        }

        // Add item at the end of the list
        void add(const T& item)
        {
            Node<T> *node = createNode(item);

            if(first == nullptr)
            {
                first = node;
                last  = node;
            }
            else
            {
                last->next = node;
                last = node;
            }

            ++size;
        }

        void add(const T& item,size_t index)
        {
            if( size == 0 )
            {
                add(item);
            }
            else if( index == 0 && size > 0 )
            {
                addToFirst(item);
            }
            else if( index >= size )
            {
                addToLast(item);
            }
            else
            {
                Node<T> *prev = first;
                Node<T> *curr = first;

                int i = 0;

                while( i++ < index  )
                {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }

                Node<T> *node = createNode(item);

                prev->next = node;
                node->next = curr;

                ++size;
            }
        }

        void addToFirst(const T& item)
        {
            Node<T> *node = createNode(item);

            node->next = first;

            first = node;

            if(size == 0)
                last = node;

            ++size;
        }

        void addToLast(const T& item)
        {
            Node<T> *node = createNode(item);

            last->next = node;

            last = node;

            if(size == 0)
                first = node;

            ++size;
        }

        void removeFirst()
        {
            if( first == nullptr )
                return;

            Node<T> *temp = first;

            first = first->next;

            --size;

            delete temp;

            if( size == 0 )
                last = first;
        }

        void remove(const size_t index)
        {
            if( size == 0 || index > size - 1 )
                throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");

            if(index == 0)
            {
                removeFirst();
                return;
            }

            Node<T> *curr = first;
            Node<T> *prev = first;

            size_t i(0);

            while( i++ < index )
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            if( curr == last )
            {
                last = prev;
            }

            prev->next = curr->next;

            delete curr;

            --size;
        }

        void removeLast()
        {
            if( first == nullptr )
                return;

            Node<T> *curr = first;
            Node<T> *prev = first;

            while( curr != last )
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            prev->next = nullptr;

            delete last;

            last = prev;

            --size;

            if( size == 0 )
                first = last;
        }

        T& getItem(size_t index) const
        {
            if(index > size)
                throw std::out_of_range("index out of bound!");

            Node<T> *curr = first;

            size_t i = 0;

            while ( i++ != index )
                curr = curr->next;

            return curr->data;
        }

        size_t length() const
        {
            return size;
        }

        iterator begin()
        {
            return iterator(first);
        }

        iterator end()
        {
            return iterator(last); //getting error here
        }

        const_iterator begin() const
        {
            return const_iterator(first);
        }

        const_iterator end() const
        {
            const_iterator(last);
        }

        ~LinkedList()
        {
            Node<T> *curr = first;

            while( curr != last )
            {
                Node<T> *temp = curr;

                curr = curr->next;

                delete temp;
            }
        }           
};


#endif /* LinkedListIterative_h */
```

The error i am getting is:

```
Error C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'Node<T> *const ' to 'Iterator<const T>'
```

The caller of this inside main is:

```
void printList(const LinkedList<int>& list)
{
    size_t index = 0;

    LinkedList<int>::const_iterator iter = list.begin();

    for(; iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    while( index < list.length() )
    {
        std::cout << list.getItem(index ++) << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Hope this [list implementation](https://github.com/Jameeeees/sgi-stl/blob/master/tass-sgi-stl-2.91.57-source/stl_list.h) will help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error in `const_iterator begin() const` and `const_iterator end() const` methods because you are trying to pass a pointer to `Node<T>` while `const_iterator` constructor accepts a pointer to `Node<const T>`. You seem to messed up `const` placement. Try changing your iterator class so both mutable and const variants accept a pointer to (possibly const-qualified) `Node<T>`.

Also `const_iterator end() const` lacks return statement;

Comment: So you are implying that i should define another Iterator class for accepting const T.

Comment: Not really, this can be achieved with only one iterator class.

Answer (score 1):

Because your const_iterator is a type `Iterator<const T>`, while the converting constructor `Iterator(const Node<const t> *)` is missing.

To be honest, I don't think it's correct to define a const_iterator like this, when the data type is corresponding to a node. Because in such a way, you will have two different node types: `Node<T>` and `Node<const T>`.

Comment: So what would be the best way to define const_iterator for such cases.

Comment: A typical way of doing this, is allowing your iterator template accept two different pointer types and reference types. Define your iterator like this `template <class T, class Pointer, class Reference> class Iterator`, and then use the correct pointer/reference type as a return type of their member functions.

Comment: Then use `typedef Iterator<T, T*, T&> iterator; typedef Iterator<T, const T*, const T&> const_iterator;`

Comment: Inside the Iterator class, for example the signature of * operator would become: `Reference operator *()`. If it's an iterator, it would return `T&`, otherwise if it's a const_iterator, it would return `const T&`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. I will try it now.