# C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'template <const T>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, compiler-errors, c++20

I got the error `C2440`: `'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'template <const T>'`.
There are [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369851/error-c2440-initializing-cannot-convert-from-const-mynamespacemytype-t) [C2440](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042143/c-c2440-function-style-cast-cannot-convert-from-nodet-const-to-ite) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444299/how-to-fix-function-style-cast-error-cannot-convert-from-initializer-list-t) but the answers did not work for my program.

MSVS 2022 gives the error twice, for each of the following:

```
template <typename T> cArray<T>::const_iterator 
cArray<T>::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(*(this), 0);              // error #1 here
}

template <typename T> cArray<T>::const_iterator 
cArray<T>::end() const
{
    return const_iterator(*this, this->m_capacity); // error #2 here
}
```

How do I fix this?

`cArray.hpp`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>

// forward declaration
template <typename T>
class cArrayIterator;

template <typename T>
class cArray
{
public:
    using value_type      = T;
    using size_type       = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference       = value_type&;
    using const_reference = value_type const&;
    using pointer         = value_type*;
    using const_pointer   = value_type const*;
    using iterator        = cArrayIterator<T>;
    using const_iterator  = cArrayIterator<T const>;

    // constructor(s)
    cArray(std::size_t);
    explicit cArray(const T&, ...) noexcept;
    cArray(T&&, ...);

    constexpr const_pointer at(size_type const);
    constexpr const_reference back() const noexcept; 
    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    constexpr size_type capacity() const noexcept;
    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;
    constexpr const_reference front() const noexcept;

    // operators
    constexpr pointer operator[](size_type const pos);
    constexpr const_pointer const operator[](size_type const) const;

private:
    friend cArrayIterator<T>;

    value_type * m_arr;
    std::size_t  m_capacity;
};

template<class T>
cArray(const T&, const T&) -> cArray<T&>;

template<class T>
explicit cArray(T&&, T&&)->cArray<T>;

template <typename T>
class cArrayIterator
{
public:
    using iterator_type     = cArrayIterator<T>;
    using value_type        = T;
    using size_type         = std::size_t;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference         = value_type&;
    using const_reference   = value_type const&;
    using pointer           = value_type*;
    using const_pointer     = value_type const*;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    explicit cArrayIterator
    (
        cArray<T>&      array,
        size_type const index
    )
    : m_array_ref(array), m_index(index)
    { 
    }

    bool operator==(iterator_type const&) const;
    bool operator!=(iterator_type const&) const;

    const_reference operator*() const;
    const_reference operator->() const;
    reference operator*();
    reference operator->();

    cArrayIterator<T>& operator++();
    iterator_type operator++(int);
    cArrayIterator<T>& operator--();
    iterator_type operator--(int);
    iterator_type operator+(difference_type) const;
    difference_type operator+(iterator_type const&) const;
    iterator_type operator-(difference_type) const;
    difference_type operator-(iterator_type const&) const;
    cArrayIterator<T>& operator +=(difference_type const);
    cArrayIterator<T>& operator -=(difference_type const);
    bool operator<(iterator_type const&) const;
    bool operator>(iterator_type const&) const;
    bool operator<=(iterator_type const&) const;
    bool operator>=(iterator_type const&) const;

    pointer operator[](size_type);
    const_pointer operator[](size_type) const;

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<cArray<T>> m_array_ref;
    size_type  m_index = 0;
};
```

`cArray.cpp`

```
#include ".\cArray.hpp"

template <typename T>
cArray<T>::cArray
(
    std::size_t capacity
)
{
    if (capacity > 0)
    {
        this->m_capacity = capacity;
        this->m_arr = new T[capacity];
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("array cannot be 0!"); // TO DO: custom exception 
    }
}

template<typename T>
cArray<T>::cArray
(
    const T& t, ...
)
noexcept
{
}

template<typename T>
cArray<T>::cArray
(
    T&& t, ...
)
{
}

template <typename T>
constexpr cArray<T>::const_pointer
cArray<T>::at
(
    size_type const index
)
{
    if (index < this->m_capacity)
    {
        return ((const T*) &this->m_arr[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: index out of bounds."); // TO DO: custom exception 
    }
}

template <typename T>
constexpr cArray<T>::const_reference
cArray<T>::back
(
)
const noexcept
{
    return this->m_arr[this->m_capacity - 1];
}

template <typename T>
constexpr cArray<T>::size_type
cArray<T>::capacity
(
)
const noexcept
{
    return this->m_capacity;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr cArray<T>::const_reference 
cArray<T>::front
(
)
    const noexcept
{
    return this->m_arr[(size_type)0];
}

/*******************************  IIb. ITERATOR METHODS  *******************************/
template <typename T>
cArray<T>::iterator 
cArray<T>::begin()
{
    return iterator(*this, 0);
}

template <typename T>
cArray<T>::iterator 
cArray<T>::end()
{
    return iterator(*this, this->m_capacity);
}

template <typename T>
cArray<T>::const_iterator 
cArray<T>::begin
(
) 
const
{
    return const_iterator(*this, 0);
}

template <typename T>
cArray<T>::const_iterator
cArray<T>::end
(
) 
const
{
    return const_iterator(*this, this->m_capacity);
}

/***  III. OPERATORS  ***/
template <typename T>
constexpr cArray<T>::pointer
cArray<T>::operator[]
(
    size_type const pos
)
{
    return (this->m_arr + pos);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr cArray<T>::const_pointer const 
cArray<T>::operator[]
(
    size_type const pos
) 
const
{
    return (this->m_arr + pos);
}

/*******************************************************************************
                              class cArrayIterator                              
*******************************************************************************/

/***************************  III.  OPERATORS  *************************/
template <typename T>
bool 
cArrayIterator<T>::operator==
(
    iterator_type const& other
)
const
{
    return ((this->m_array_ref.get().m_arr == other.m_array_ref.get().m_arr) && 
            (this->m_index == other.m_index));
}

template <typename T>
bool 
cArrayIterator<T>::operator!=
(
    iterator_type const& other
)
const
{
    return ((this->m_array_ref.get().m_arr != other.m_array_ref.get().m_arr) || 
            (this->m_index != other.m_index));
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::const_reference 
cArrayIterator<T>::operator*
(
) 
const
{
    // make sure array is within bounds
    if ((this->m_index > 0) || 
        (this->m_index < this->m_array_ref.get().m_capacity))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("TO DO: Cannot dereferentiate the iterator");
    }
            
    return this->m_array_ref.get().m_arr[this->m_index];
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::const_reference
cArrayIterator<T>::operator->
(
)
const
{
    // make sure array is within bounds
    if ((this->m_index > 0) ||
        (this->m_index < this->m_array_ref.get().m_capacity))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("TO DO: Cannot dereferentiate the iterator");
    }

    return this->m_array_ref.get().m_arr[this->m_index];
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::reference
cArrayIterator<T>::operator*
(
)
{
    // make sure array is within bounds
    if ((this->m_index > 0) ||
        (this->m_index < this->m_array_ref.get().m_capacity))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("TO DO: Cannot dereferentiate the iterator");
    }

    return this->m_array_ref.get().m_arr[this->m_index];
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::reference
cArrayIterator<T>::operator->
(
)
{
    // make sure array is within bounds
    if ((this->m_index > 0) ||
        (this->m_index < this->m_array_ref.get().m_capacity))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("TO DO: Cannot dereferentiate the iterator");
    }

    return this->m_array_ref.get().m_arr[this->m_index];
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>&
cArrayIterator<T>::operator++
(
)
{
    if (this->m_index >= this->m_array_ref.get().m_capacity)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: index out of bounds!");
    }
    
    this->m_index++;

    return *(this);
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::iterator_type
cArrayIterator<T>::operator++
(
    int
)
{
    iterator_type temp = *(this);

    ++*this;

    return temp;
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>&
cArrayIterator<T>::operator--
(
)
{
    if (this->m_index <= 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: index out of bounds!");
    }

    this->m_index--;

    return *(this);
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::iterator_type
cArrayIterator<T>::operator--
(
    int
)
{
    iterator_type temp = *(this);

    --*this;

    return temp;
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::iterator_type
cArrayIterator<T>::operator+
(
    difference_type offset
)
const
{
    iterator_type temp = *this;

    return temp += offset;
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::difference_type
cArrayIterator<T>::operator+
(
    iterator_type const& other
) 
const
{
    return this->m_index + other.m_index;
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::iterator_type
cArrayIterator<T>::operator-
(
    difference_type offset
) 
const
{
    iterator_type temp = *this;

    return temp -= offset;
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::difference_type
cArrayIterator<T>::operator-
(
    iterator_type const& other
)
const
{
    return this->m_index - other.m_index;
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>&
cArrayIterator<T>::operator+=
(
    difference_type const offset
)
{
    difference_type next = this->m_index + offset;

    if (next >= this->m_array_ref.get().m_capacity)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: Iterator cannot be incremented past the bounds of the range");
    }
    
    this->m_index = next;

    return *(this);
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>&
cArrayIterator<T>::operator-=
(
    difference_type const offset
    )
{
    difference_type next = this->m_index - offset;

    if (next > 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: Iterator cannot be incremented past the bounds of the range");
    }

    this->m_index = next;

    return *(this);
}

template<typename T>
bool 
cArrayIterator<T>::operator<
(
    iterator_type const& other
)
const
{
    return (this->m_index < other.m_index);
}

template <typename T>
bool
cArrayIterator<T>::operator>
(
    iterator_type const& other
)   
const
{
    return other < *(this);
}

template <typename T>
bool cArrayIterator<T>::operator<=
(
    iterator_type const& other
)   
const
{
    return !(other < *(this));
}

template <typename T>
bool
cArrayIterator<T>::operator>=
(
    iterator_type const& other
)   
const
{
    return !(*(this) < other);
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::pointer
cArrayIterator<T>::operator[]
(
    size_type index
)
{
    if (index >= this->m_array.get().m_capacity)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: index out of range.");
    }

    return (this->m_array.get().m_arr + index);
}

template <typename T>
cArrayIterator<T>::const_pointer
cArrayIterator<T>::operator[]
(
    size_type index
)   
const
{
    if (index >= this->m_array.get().m_capacity)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("TO DO: index out of range.");
    }

    return (this->m_array.get().m_arr + index);
}
```

`cArrayImpl.cpp`

```
#include "cArray.cpp"

template class cArray<int>;
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "cArray.hpp"
#include "cArrayImpl.cpp"


int
main
(
    int     argc,
    char ** argv
)
{
    std::cout << "Testing cArray module..." << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Testing constructor: " << std::endl;
    cArray<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

### Update #1

So I ran this through clang and got a much more descriptive error message:

`no matching constructor for initialization of 'cArray<int>::const_iterator' (aka 'cArrayIterator<const int>')`

I am guessing that because `const T` is a different type than `T` it cannot find a matching function signature.
And presumably never will, because for any `T`, `const T` will *always* be a different type?

I also got the following **8** messages (not error, just message):

Appeared **2x** each:

- `candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided`
- `candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided`
- `candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const cArray<int>' to 'cArray<const int>&' for 1st arugment`

Appeared **1x** each:

- `in instantiation of member function 'cArray<int>::begin' requested here`
- `in instantiation of member function 'cArray<int>::end' requested here`

Any further input would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Unrelated: `constexpr const_pointer const operator[](size_type const) const;` - you are going overboard with the `const`-ness. The `const_pointer` shouldn't be `const` and it's also pointless in this context. Just make it `constexpr const_pointer operator[](size_type const) const;`

Comment: Hmm, MSVC doesn't give me a compilation error for the code you've posted. https://godbolt.org/z/sjhbWadW9 - (the only change I made was to remove the pointless `const` but it compiles even with it)

Comment: You might also want to read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/17398063)

Comment: @273K sorry forgot to add `main` and `cArrayImpl.cpp`, fixed now

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're right, not sure how that slipped in there but fixed.  And godbolt is working fine for me as well but not in MSVC.  I wonder why this is?

Comment: @BoP I have a cArrayImpl.cpp, which I edited OP to show.

Comment: It is a good choice to refer to Ted's reply. As for why it behaves differently in different compilers, this may be related to the standards implemented by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```cpp
template <typename T> 
cArray<T>::const_iterator 
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
cArray<T>::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(*(this), 0);              // error #1 here
}
```

you create a **dependent scope**. This is a common mistake with templates: The `cArray<T>` type depends on `T`, so the compiler cannot know about its **members** (among others). So what is `cArray<T>::const_iterator` it wonders ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f480d58a28710e)), and you are responsible to fill in that information saying it's a type:

```cpp
template <typename T> 
typename cArray<T>::const_iterator 
// ^^^^^ 
cArray<T>::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(*(this), 0);              // error #1 here
}
```

Do that (in multiple places) and you should compile as shown in the following [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e4ef49a04481d9f) - albeit that uses g++, I could only verify in my local Visual Studio 2022, where missing the `typename` resulted in these errors (with  /std:c++17):

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'iterator'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Incidentally, that's the reason we have `_t` helper types in the standard library e.g.:

```cpp
template< std::size_t I, class T >
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<I, T>::type;
```

Comment: I added your changes and had no success in MSVC, but as mentioned in the OP comments it runs in godbolt.  Any idea as to what could cause this?

Comment: Although this was absolutely necessary to make it work in clang!

Comment: @SKNB Which visual studio version are you using and with what settings in your project, namely "Windows SDK version", "Platform Toolset" and "C++ language standard". For me it works with 10.0, v143 and `/std:c++17` respectively